# Can we offload OpenMp to any Intel GPU?

Tags: gpu, openmp, intel, gpgpu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Is there a way to use openMp and offload the parallel code into the Intel GPUs such as Intel HD graphics ?

If yes:

2. which icc version do I need ? (can I do it with gcc ?)
3. which Intel processors are supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can only offload OpenMP code on Intel MIC/Xeon Phi.
However in the (near ?) future OpenMP 4 should offer this kind of feature (see this [post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/05/openmp-40-may-offer-important-solutions-for-targeting-and-vectorization)).

So GPGPU on Intel HD graphics can only be done with OpenCL and Intel CILK for the moment I think.

Comment: Just to be sure that I read the post correctly - In the future we could offload openMp to HD GRAPHICS (like those on the 4Gd processors) ?

Comment: Well I said "should" not "could". we can never know...  I am still waiting for the Larrabee btw :)

Comment: You can also use Direct Compute http://www.anandtech.com/show/7711/floating-point-peak-performance-of-kaveri-and-other-recent-amd-and-intel-chips. In fact fp64 requires Direct Compute, it does not work with OpenCL with Intel HD.

Answer (score 0):

Some OpenMP 4 constructs work on Intel GPUs with the Intel C/C++ compiler.

I've tested the following code on Xeon E3, probably Haswell (v3) generation and with Intel compiler version 15 or 16 (probably the latter).  I tested on Linux and find that it is not supported on Mac.

```
void vadd4(int n, float * RESTRICT a, float * RESTRICT b, float * RESTRICT c)
{
#if defined(_OPENMP) && (_OPENMP >= 201307)
    //#pragma omp target teams distribute map(to:n,a[0:n],b[0:n]) map(from:c[0:n])
    #pragma omp target map(to:n,a[0:n],b[0:n]) map(from:c[0:n])
    #pragma omp parallel for simd
#else
    #warning No OpenMP target/simd support!
    #pragma omp parallel for
#endif
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

The full test code I used to evaluate Intel GPU compute software is https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/openmp/offload/test_vadd.c.

Unfortunately, the `distribute` and `teams` are not supported for the `-qopenmp-offload=gfx` target, so one needs some preprocessing to generate functionally portable code.

Additional documentation includes:

- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-offload-computation-to-intelr-graphics-technology
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pldi-tutorial-using-the-intelr-c-compiler-for-general-purpose-computation-offload-to-intelr

Disclaimer: I work for Intel, but in a research capacity.  I am not responsible for implementing or supporting the Intel compiler or Intel GPU software.